# javascript onchange property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just have this problem on my page, which is..
I want the options of a select dropdown list to be changed on everytime the user select a different option from this select list, I used "onchange" property, it worked well for only first time! but not on every change of selection ! here is my code,

```js
var SlctYear = document.getElementById("SlctYear"),
  SlctMonth = document.getElementById("SlctMonth"),
  SlctDay = document.getElementById("SlctDay"),
  x,
  option1,
  option2,
  option3;

for (x = 2017; x >= 1960; x -= 1) {
  option1 = document.createElement("option");
  SlctYear.appendChild(option1);
  option1.textContent = x;
  option1.setAttribute("value", "Val" + x);
}

for (x = 1; x <= 12; x += 1) {
  option2 = document.createElement("option");
  SlctMonth.appendChild(option2);
  option2.textContent = x;
  option2.setAttribute("value", "Val" + x);
}

SlctMonth.onchange = function() {
  "use strict";
  if (SlctMonth.options[0].selected || SlctMonth.options[2].selected || SlctMonth.options[4].selected || SlctMonth.options[6].selected || SlctMonth.options[7].selected || SlctMonth.options[9].selected || SlctMonth.options[11].selected === true) {
    for (x = 31; x >= 1; x -= 1) {
      option3 = document.createElement("option");
      SlctDay.appendChild(option3);
      option3.textContent = x;
    }
  } else if (SlctMonth.options[1].selected === true) {
    for (x = 28; x >= 1; x -= 1) {
      option3 = document.createElement("option");
      SlctDay.appendChild(option3);
      option3.textContent = x;
    }
  } else if (SlctMonth.options[3].selected || SlctMonth.options[5].selected || SlctMonth.options[8].selected || SlctMonth.options[10].selected) {
    for (x = 30; x >= 1; x -= 1) {
      option3 = document.createElement("option");
      SlctDay.appendChild(option3);
      option3.textContent = x;
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<label>Year</label>
<select id="SlctYear"></select>
<br>
<label>Month</label>
<select id="SlctMonth"></select>
<br>
<label>Day</label>
<select id="SlctDay"></select>
```

Comment: If you create a date of new Date(yyyy,mm,0) you get the last day in mm so no need to test for leap or days in month

Comment: The title of your post should be a brief description of your question, not the search terms you used to Google the problem or your hashtags.  Stack Overflow is not Twitter, Facebook or a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you don't clear options before you append new ones, just add loop in your function as below:

```
 SlctMonth.onchange = function() {
          "use strict";
          //ADD THIS-------------------------
          while (SlctDay.hasChildNodes()) {
            SlctDay.removeChild(SlctDay.lastChild);
          }
          //--------------------------------
          if (SlctMonth.options[0].selected || SlctMonth.options[2].selected || SlctMonth.options[4].selected || SlctMonth.options[6].selected || SlctMonth.options[7].selected || SlctMonth.options[9].selected || SlctMonth.options[11].selected === true) {
            for (x = 31; x >= 1; x -= 1) {
              option3 = document.createElement("option");
              SlctDay.appendChild(option3);
              option3.textContent = x;
            }
          } else if (SlctMonth.options[1].selected === true) {
            for (x = 28; x >= 1; x -= 1) {
              option3 = document.createElement("option");
              SlctDay.appendChild(option3);
              option3.textContent = x;
            }
          } else if (SlctMonth.options[3].selected || SlctMonth.options[5].selected || SlctMonth.options[8].selected || SlctMonth.options[10].selected) {
            for (x = 30; x >= 1; x -= 1) {
              option3 = document.createElement("option");
              SlctDay.appendChild(option3);
              option3.textContent = x;
            }
          }
        };
```

Comment: Wonderful Man ! Thanks a Lot! :D